# How to enable auto search in Android application while fetching data from external server

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

I searched for the problem and found this link:

[Auto Search in Android app while fetching data from external server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350519/auto-search-in-android-app-while-fetching-data-from-external-server)

but unfortunately we don't have any response for this.

I have an Android application which is getting the list of products from server. In the search window, I am initiating the search when user has entered more than or equal to 3 characters in the search box. I have put a check on the length and sending Async request when length is more than or equal to 3. My issue is that the code is sending request everytime I enter a new character i.e. when I want to search for Samsung, my search initiates after typing 'Sam'. Now when I type 'sung' very quickly, then code will send Async request to all new added characters and hence even after entering the complete word, the search continuous in the backend and hence updates the result continuously.

Is there any way that I can cancel the intermediate requests when I am moving from Sam to Samsung quickly by inserting some delay. It looks very weird that user has stopped typing and search results are still updating.

Comment: what "intermediate requests" are you talking about? who sends it?

Comment: Let me try and rephrase the question. I am using SearchView and in onQueryTextChange(), I have put a check that if(query.length() >= 3) then send an Async request to my server asking for possible word matches.

Now, at every new character, the code will send a new Async request. If I type Samsung as my search query and that too very quickly then code will send an Async request of Sam, then Sams, then Samsu and so on...

I want that my code should be able to tap that while an Async request is in process, and multiple characters have been added then it should avoid intermediate Async requests.

Comment: so don't  send them if the previous request is not finished, btw why aren't you using AutoCompleteTextView?

Comment: ACTV makes for you almost you want, no async task needed,  no requests scheduler,  no special presenter for the results...